# is it possible to publish gradle module metadata to oss.sontatype.org?

Tags: java, gradle, sonatype

I'm trying to publish a jar to oss.sontatype.org using `id 'maven-publish'` (gradle 6.8.1).

Problem is that by default gradle publishes its module metadata and sonatype.org does not seem to like that. What happens is that sonatype does not list the jar artifact anymore. All I see (in the sontype ui) is:

```
myproject-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
myproject-SNAPSHOT-source.jar
myproject-SNAPSHOT.module
```

The jar is missing although I can see in the gradle log that it uploads the jar.

If I disable the gradle metadata

```
tasks.withType(GenerateModuleMetadata) {
    enabled = false
}
```

I see the expected files:

```
myproject-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
myproject-SNAPSHOT-source.jar
myproject-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I wonder if it is possible to publish gradle module metadata to oss.sonatype.org?

Here is my publishing configuration [on github](https://github.com/openapi-processor/openapi-processor-core/blob/master/gradle/publishing.gradle) and inline:

```
// does not work on oss.sonatype.org
tasks.withType(GenerateModuleMetadata) {
    enabled = false
}

publishing {
    publications {
        OpenApiProcessor (MavenPublication) {
            groupId project.group
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version

            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar

            pom {
                name = project.projectTitle
                description = project.projectDesc
                url = project.projectUrl

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                        distribution = "repo"
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'hauner'
                        name  = 'Martin Hauner'
                    }
                }

                scm {
                   url = "https://github.com/${project.projectGithubRepo}".toString ()
                }
            }

        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            def releaseRepository = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
            def snapshotRepository = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
            url = project.isReleaseVersion ? releaseRepository : snapshotRepository

            credentials {
                username = publishUser
                password = publishKey
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(Sign) {
    onlyIf { project.isReleaseVersion }
}

signing {
    useInMemoryPgpKeys(signKey, signPwd)

    signing {
        sign publishing.publications.OpenApiProcessor
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your publishing configuration since I disagree here and it's likely due to way you have setup publishing. I currently publish both the module metadata and JAR artifact for snapshots to sonatype: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/mateo/cxf-codegen-gradle/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Added the configuration. On a quick scan of your configuration I don't see anything that looks suspicious to me.